# Domain driven programming and events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design

I'm doing some asp.net mvc coding using DDD. I have objects representing the business entities and service repositories that handle fetching and adding them. I'm new to this and as my application grows I begin to see a lot of secondary code that must run as a result of adding, deleting or changing my domain objects/data.

I'd like to make an event driven system where one action triggers other parts of code to run. For instance when I delete a user I want to be able to subscribe a number of other things to this action so they all are run when a delete takes place.

How have you coded your applications to handle these situations? How can I establish a reliable and coherent OO system for my problem? I already know about events and delegates but I'm more interested in coding techniques and nice practices.

Comment: In .net this is usually done through the interfaces INotifyPropertyChanged and IObservableCollection. A lot of DataSet-gui-Magic is implemented this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thing You might want to check out are so called [domain events](http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=280). Basically idea is that domain model itself triggers domain specific events (e.g. `CustomerRegistered`) and pretty much anything You like can subscribe to them to do additional stuff outside of domain.

Udi Dahan wrote some nice articles on this: [1st](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/), [2nd](http://www.udidahan.com/2008/08/25/domain-events-take-2/), [3rd](http://www.udidahan.com/2008/02/29/how-to-create-fully-encapsulated-domain-models/).

Also - [sample application](http://dddsamplenet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/48934#777709) by Szymon is quite explanatory on this.

CQRS is great, but it affects whole architecture. Might be an overkill.

Comment: This answer is along the line of thing I was thinking to implement

Comment: This is a very nice answer. Thanks for sharing those articles Arnis. I haven't been able to find them through Google. Thanks!